# Get video thumbnail from external URL

Tags: android, video-capture

I'm wondering what's the best practice to get thumbnails of videos on an external URL, i.e. HTTP videos that can be streamed.

I've tried using `ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()`, and that works excellently for local videos, but doesn't work for videos on the web.

I've thought about a partial download of the file, and then see if it's somehow possible to get a thumbnail based on that, but I haven't tried it yet.

Any suggestions or thoughts?

Comment: Check if the video information itself has the thumbnail URL. Many of the Streaming servers do send this information

Comment: There isn't any in this case :)